# `Group By` returns empty rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Please have a look at the below code.

```
SELECT ongoing_portfolio.*,
    Portfolio.Activation,
    SUM(case when Transaction_TimeStamp <= ongoing_portfolio.`Updated_Date` 
        then Transactions.`Transaction_Amount` ELSE 0 end) AS `Total` 
    FROM Ongoing_Portfolio
    INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio
    INNER JOIN Transactions ON Transactions.`idPortfolio` = Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio
    WHERE ongoing_portfolio.`idPortfolio`= 5        
    GROUP BY Ongoing_Portfolio.`Updated_Date`  DESC LIMIT 4
```

This works fine "only" if there is "at least" 1 transaction for the particular `portfolio`. If there are no transactions at all for that portfolio, then it simply returns empty row, which means nothing.

I tried grouping with `Ongoing_Portfolio.idOngoing_Portfolio`, `Transactions.idTransactions`, `Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio` but no good at all. Why this is happening like this?

Comment: Use a `left join` instead of `inner join`

Comment: @juergend: OK, but at what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 INNER JOIN Transactions ON Transactions.`idPortfolio` = Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio
```

by

```
 LEFT JOIN Transactions ON Ongoing_Portfolio.idPortfolio = Transactions.`idPortfolio`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN